# PowerApps - Save data entries to empty data table, and save in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, power-platform

I have made the following screen in Power Apps:
[image]

**My goal is simple:** I wish the end-user to enter data into these text boxes -> User clicks "OK" button -> Data is saved for the user right below in a relational data table with columns; Name, Amount, and Measure.

Once all data entries are made, a "Save" button should send the complete data table in JSON format as input for a SQL Server stored procedure, which accepts the parameter @json. How is this accomplished?

**What I tried**: Tried making a gallery, data table, form, etc. But all of these require me to connect to an existing data set. I instead want the user to create the data set, and *then* have the data sent to a SQL Server database.

Comment: PowerApps is not part of Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use the [built-in SQL Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/connections/connection-azure-sqldatabase)**

- Create the table in the SQL database
- Add the SQL Connector to your PowerApp
- Authenticate to the connector
- Select the table to connect to
- Then write your Patch() logic accordingly
- You don't need a Stored Procedure

As an alternative, if you realllly want to use a Stored Procedure, connect Power Automate to your PowerApp and run the Stored Procedure from there. This introduces dependencies though. Your call. [Example](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6857/call-sql-server-stored-procedure-from-power-apps/)

**Beware:**

- If you *don't* setup the SQL Server with Active Directory Auth, you will share **your** permissions, **implicitly**, with whomever you share the PowerApp with.
- Best to use SQL to create a Group, Assign Role(s) to the Group, then assign Users to the Group
- Then each user of the PowerApp will have to **explicitly** authenticate using *their* perms
- See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/connections/sql-server-security#difference-between-explicit-and-implicit-connections)